# How to erase an object of a list containing pointers to a struct?

Tags: c++, list, struct, erase

I have a struct called Node with 3 members, one of which acts as an id for the objects:

```cpp
struct Node {
  string mem1;
  string mem2;
  int id;
}
```

And a list containing pointers to Node objects:

```cpp
list<Node*> g_node;
```

The problem comes when trying to erase a specific object from that list (localized by the id). I have this code but doesn't work:

```cpp
list<Node>::iterator it = g_node.begin();
            while (it != g_node.end()){
                if (it->id == iden)
                {
                    g_node->erase(it);
                }
            }
        } else if (iden != 0) {
```

"iden" is the id of an object to be deleted, and is input by the user.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Did you forget `++it`? Also, will there be only one entry in the `list` with `id` same as `iden`? If yes, you can `break` the loop on successful erase. If no, you should use erase-remove idiom.

Comment: When iterating over a container and erasing an element use the returned iterator (!) of erase as the next valid iterator (erase may make the iterator passed to erase invalid)

Comment: `g_node->erase(it);` should fail to compile, there is no `operator->` defined for `std::list`.

Comment: If you don't need the insertion order preserved, consider using `std::map` or `std::multimap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove_if is a great idea, but if you want to have a function that you can easily reuse and customize at your will, you can do it like this:

```
bool remove_from_list(int id, list<Node*> &g_node)
{
    auto it = g_node.begin();

    while (it != g_node.end())
    {
        if ((*it)->id == id)
        {
            // free memory... if you allocated those pointers
            delete (*it); 
            g_node.erase(it);
            return true;
        }
        else
            it++;
    }

    return false;
}

list<Node*> g_node;
g_node.push_back(new Node { "a", "b", 5 });
g_node.push_back(new Node { "ee", "77", 6 });
remove_from_list(5, g_node);
```

Comment: because my code does, and I thought maybe his does as well, and probably forgot to free it. That's why I wrote my answer  with new and delete (I was actually considering to give my answer without the delete part... but I think that's dumb)

Comment: That's a big assumption to make. Maybe it is better to ask OP for clarification.

Comment: My comment was too long it wasn't easy to read. It's smaller now. "// free memory... if you allocated those pointers" That should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [`std::list::remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove_if/)?

```
g_node.remove_if([iden](const Node *n){return n->id == iden;});
```

---

Note that this will not `delete` the `Node` object (neither does your original code). With containers holding pointers, you might want to consider smart pointers.

Comment: note for readers: `list::remove_if` has different semantics to `std::remove_if`: the latter moves elements without erasing them, but the `list` version does actually erase them.